# Q: Search Bar and Search Display Controller in storyboard with swift and Xcode8.0 crash at Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, searchdisplaycontroller

Storyboard layout is below:

[image: This is my storyboard layout]

This is my demo, and I don't know where the error comes out.

In `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


@IBOutlet var searchDisplay: UISearchDisplayController!

var ctrls:[String] = ["Label","Button1-init","Button1-high","Button2-init","Button2-high","Switch"]

var ctrlsel:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.ctrlsel = self.ctrls
    self.searchDisplay.searchResultsTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                                                            forCellReuseIdentifier: "SwiftCell")

    self.searchDisplay.searchBar.placeholder = "input"

    //self.searchDisplay.searchBar.text = "b"

    self.searchDisplay.searchBar.prompt = "search"

    self.searchDisplay.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal

    self.searchDisplay.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    self.searchDisplay.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["all","part","high"]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.ctrlsel.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    -> UITableViewCell!
{

    let identify:String = "SwiftCell"

    let cell = self.searchDisplay.searchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: identify, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.ctrlsel[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, textDidChange searchText: String!) {
    self.searchText = searchText
    searchCtrls()
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    print(selectedScope)
    searchCtrls();
}

var searchText:String = ""


func searchCtrls() {

    if self.searchText == "" {
        self.ctrlsel = self.ctrls
    }
    else {
        var scope = self.searchDisplay.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;

        self.ctrlsel = []
        for ctrl in self.ctrls {
            let lc = ctrl.lowercased()
            if lc.hasPrefix(self.searchText) {
                if (scope == 0 || (scope == 1 && lc.hasSuffix("init"))
                    || (scope == 2 && lc.hasSuffix("high"))) {
                    self.ctrlsel.append(ctrl)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    // self.searchDisplay.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
}

}
```

Crash at Appdelegate. In the `swift3` and `Xcode 8.0` environment. To convenient get search result ,use `Search Bar and Search Display Controller in storyboard`.

When I run my application, it crash at :`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`  this line in `Appdelegate.swift`.The break info is : `Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1`

**EDIT:**

after set `dataSource` and `delegate` of tableView to `vc`: there comes a strange scenario：the `searchbar` is under the `tableView`

Comment: you missing tableView  and searchBar class..

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error that you're getting?

Comment: Ok I see the error in the screenshot, one quick question have you set the datasource and delegate for the tableview as your viewcontroller ?

Comment: now I set it.and I will implement the protocol too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have set the **datasource** and the **delegate** of the tableview incorrectly, please set the **datasource** and **delegate** either in the interface builder as shown in the below screenshot,

[image: Select the tableview and set the data source in the connection inspector]

Select the tableview and set the data source in the connection inspector.

Or you can do this via code, by setting them in your viewDidLoad() method. Paste these lines in viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

As I can see from your code snippet that you've pasted, you've already implemented the UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource methods. But you've not mentioned that your class conforms to these protocols so modify your class declaration and specify that your class conforms to these protocols.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
//Your class implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: I do that and I found a strange issue again, could you see that?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, could you let me know what is the strange issue that you're facing ?

Comment: I edited my post yesterday, and last night i have take a whole example of `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`,the issue is in the question, now I have get a good example of my need.

Comment: Could you set the searchbar as the tableview header ? 
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchDisplay.searchBar